# AsyncTask and Activity how to do it

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My main application does this: It retrievs data from the internet and has 3 button, when OnClicked, i am going to 3 other screens. because the data loading may be a little slow, I want to use an async Task. This is my sample code for asynctask.

```
class LoginProgressTask extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(4000);  // Do your real work here
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return Boolean.TRUE;   // Return your real result here
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showDialog(AUTHORIZING_DIALOG);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // result is the value returned from doInBackground
            removeDialog(AUTHORIZING_DIALOG);
        }
}
```

and this is my sample of my main activity:

```
public class MainScreen extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MainTheme();
    }
    public void MainTheme(){
         retrieve_data(); //function for getting the data
         ... action with the buttons, onClicks Listener
    }
}
```

My question is how can I mix those codes in One activity to make it work, becuase I haven't understood AsyncTask. Or what I should return in the doInBackground?

Comment: I am not so sure I understand the problem. You have an activity that launches the asynctask, and is your question what happens to the task once you press one of the buttons which puts you into activities?

Comment: The first code is the sample that I found on the web. And I want to insertit on myScreen Activity so sa to make this activity loading, while the function retrieves data. and when tthis function finishes, my loading bar to dissappear.

Comment: this would be totally different than what I understood before. In this case, all functionality is in the AsyncTask. your main activity simply launches it onCreate(). the AsyncTask can be taken directly form the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned it from >> [AsynTask](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) link. may be it will helpful to you too, first read the whole example then start applying it on your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Service` instead of `AsyncTask`. [This](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you have a `Button` to login, you should do something like this:

```
Button button; //Here button to go other sreen
public void onCreate(){
  //some business code here
  //notice: you have declare you button to your layout. I don't post it, but maybe you know how to
  button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        LoginProcessTask loginTask = new LoginProcessTask(this);
        login.excute(data of param1);
    }
  }
}
```

And you should notice that, in your `LoginProcessTask`, you have wrongly extended it. It must be (just for example):

```
class LoginProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Integer>{ ......}
```